# how to prevent flickering caused by useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on select component with remote data. I use react-query and axios with mantine component lib. Select will be used as custom cell in react-table.

The problem:
After selecting option, patch is send to backend, and on success data is refetched. There is flickering I cant remove without causing more bugs. Found some simillar topics, but answers to them does not work.

Value seems to change to selected one, then change for a split of second to old one, and comes back to refetched one.
[image: Gif showing problem]

```
export const PackageSizeSelect = ({ info, mutationFn, queryKey }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(info.getValue())
  }, [info])
  
  const { data: trData, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["package_sizes", "select"],
    queryFn: getPackageSizeSelectData,

  });
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: mutationFn,
    onSuccess: () => {
      setError(false);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [queryKey],
      });
    },
    onError: () => {
      setError(true);
      return queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [queryKey],
      });
    },
  });
  const handleOnOptionSubmit = (val) => {
    const v = val.toString();
    setValue(v);
    mutation.mutate({
      data: {
        [info.column.id]: v,
      },
      id: info.row.original.id,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {info.getValue()}
      {value}
      <Select
        key={info.cell.id}
        w={200}
        allowDeselect={false}
        data={trData}
        value={value}
        error={error}
        rightSection={mutation.isPending || isLoading ? <Loader size="1rem" /> : null}
        onOptionSubmit={(value) => handleOnOptionSubmit(value)}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

I attach full code of component.

I tried:

- comparing old value with new value
- removing useEffect
- using useLayoutEffect
- forcing rerender by other useState
- setting value by useRef